# (ssg-wsg) Keep getting errors with CorpPass

Tags: static-site-generation

I have assigned API access with Corp Pass but each time i log into ssg-wsg and enter my email i get the error - an error has occurred, please try again later.

Anyone else having these issues or know how to fix it?

Thanks,
Aidan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have colleague that can help to login on your behalf.

If your colleague is able to login, maybe he / she can help to perform the necessary or lodge a ticket.